# The set of all points in $x = su + tv$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My (introductory) linear algebra textbook states the following:

> The equation of the plane through three
>   noncollinear points $A$, $B$, and $C$ in space is $x = A + su + tv$, where $u$ and
>   $v$ denote the vectors beginning at $A$ and ending at $B$ and $C$, respectively,
>   and $s$ and $t$ denote arbitrary real numbers. An important special case occurs when $A$ is the origin. In this case, the equation of the plane simplifies to $x = su + tv$, and the set of all points in this plane is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I am specifically confused about how the set of all points in the plane is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I understand what subspace are, but I fail to see how the set of all points in the plane $x = su + tv$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to elaborate on and demonstrate this concept. Please use elementary concepts and mathematical language in any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that the fact that $A=0$ is very important, as this implies that the identity of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is in the subspace, which is a must. Anyway to understand why the plane is a subspace notice that any plane is generated by two non-parallel vectors. In other words every point in a plane is a linear combination of the two vectors. So hence we have that the plane $\pi$ is equal to the $\text{Span}(\vec{u},\vec{v})$, so hence it's a subspace.

In fact you can easily veryfy that the set contains the identity element is closed under both addition and scalar multiplication using the properties of vector algebra.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the response. Would you mind please also answering my query in the comments to Arun's answer?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes, $x = su + tv$ is the equation of a plane, but $x$ is a vector (the RHS is summation of vectors) hence a point in the plane. In fact the plane $\pi$ is defined as $\pi = \{\vec{x} | \vec{x} = s\vec{u} + t\vec{v}; s,t \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: ahh, I understand. So the equation of a plane is just also just the equation of a vector (in this case, all possible linear combinations of two vectors)?

Comment: @ThePointer You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a Subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we only need to show it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. So let $x,y$ be two points in the given plane, then $$x=s_1u+t_1v, y=s_2u+t_2v$$ So $$x+y=(s_1+s_2)u+(t_1+t_2)v$$ is in the plane and $$\alpha x=(\alpha s_1) u+(\alpha t_1)v$$ is also in the plane. Hence the given plane is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Do you mean $x$ and $y$ are planes -- not points?

Comment: $x,y$ are points in the plane. thanks!! stefan4024 for the edit

Comment: But it says that $x = su + tv$ is the equation of a plane starting at the origin. Doesn't that mean $x$ and $y$ are both planes?

Comment: $x=su+tv$ is the equation of a plane i.e the set of all points $x$ of the form $x=su+tv$. you have written it correctly in the Title of the question.